# what's the closest method of programming with the Aristotelian method of taxonomy?

Tags: python, oop, logic

i'm working on a Animal gessing game and i wonder if there is a similar classification scheme of genus and species. I was thinking in the equivalent of OOP with multiple inheritance.

i tried using a csv file in python with all the animals' informations. But i'm searching an OOP-like method.

Comment: I don't see how OOP and csv file are mutually exclusive. Can you [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]? (You may need to explain that Aristotelian method of taxonomy.) What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].